# Make a java completable future cache atomic

Tags: java, asynchronous, caching, atomic, completable-future

I've been trying to setup a simple atomic completable future cache that takes a `String key` and a `Callable class` and caches the executions and the results. I know I could use [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) but still want to understand how this can be done without race conditions while inserting and clearing.

In this simple class I have two simplified caches: an `executions` cache that keeps tracks of the callables that haven't finished running, and a `results` cache that keeps track of the results (this will eventually be an ehcache that overflows to disk)

```java
public class AsyncCache {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<Object>> executions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public CompletableFuture<Object> get(String key, Callable<Object> callable) {

        Object result = results.get(key);
        if (result != null) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
        }

        return executions.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {

            CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    return callable.call();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new CompletionException(e);
                }
            }, executor);

            return future.whenComplete((Object r, Throwable t) -> {
                if (executions.remove(k) != null) {
                    results.put(k, result);
                }
            });

        });

    }

    public void clear() {
        results.clear();
        executions.clear();
    }

}
```

I believe that this code has two problems. First, there is a synchronization problem in the lines:

```java
if (executions.remove(k) != null) {
    results.put(k, result);
}
```

In between `remove(k)` and `results.put(k, result)` there can be a new `get` call for the same key that is not already in `results` and has been removed from `executions`, thus triggering a new callable execution, when the result was about to be placed in the results cache.

Second, there is another synchronization problem in the lines:

```java
results.clear();
executions.clear();
```

In between both `clear()` there can be a new `get` call that would not get result from the `results` map but would get a stalled response from the `executions` map.

Any ideas on how to fix this without naively synchronizing everything.

---

Edit.

What if I introduce a lock per key to guard against read and writes? Something like this:

```java
    ConcurrentMap<String, ReadWriteLock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReadWriteLock>();

    public CompletableFuture<Object> get1(String key, Callable<Object> callable) {

        ReadWriteLock reading = locks.computeIfAbsent(key, r -> new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
        reading.readLock().lock();
        try {

            Object result = results.get(key);
            if (result != null) {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
            }

            return executions.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {

                CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        return callable.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new CompletionException(e);
                    }
                }, executor);

                return future.whenComplete((Object r, Throwable t) -> {

                    ReadWriteLock writing = locks.computeIfAbsent(k, w -> new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
                    writing.writeLock().lock();
                    try {
                        if (executions.remove(k) != null) {
                            results.put(k, r);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        writing.writeLock().unlock();
                        locks.remove(k);
                    }

                });

            });

        } finally {
            reading.readLock().unlock();
            locks.remove(key);
        }

    }
```

This would still leave with questions regarding how to write the `clear()` method.

Comment: Why do you even think you need the `results` map? When the future completes, you unwrap the result and dump it in there, but if someone requests the same key again, you have to re-wrap it with `completedFuture` again. Feels like you only need a single map with all the futures in it, regardless of whether their current state is finished or not.

Comment: @michael the `results` map would eventually overflow to disk and the completable futures can't be serialized. I'm with you if this would be an always in memory cache. but it will not be the case.

Comment: Feels like you could fix that much more easily with some custom serialization logic. Your solution incurs a massive runtime penalty for something that ultimately might not even happen.

Comment: The code that you call out as potentially having a synchronized problem could be done in a `computeIfPresent` I believe.

Comment: @Michael this is meant to run in a memory restricted environment and the calculations that get cache could be very large and very time consuming. The logic of what gets sent to disk would be more complex, but would like to solve this at this simpler level. I need to decouple the execution from the result.

Comment: How is this “overflow to disk” supposed to work together with atomic updates? And how is it supposed to save memory, if not by removing the result from heap and obviously, re-fetching it on demand? How is *that* supposed to work transparently and still maintaining the desired atomicity?

Comment: @Holger The overflow to disk will be handled by using a correctly configured EHCache instead of the `results` map. As per saving memory, if I have hundreds of results in disk, I only need to bring to memory the one being requested. EHCache would handle the move to disk and back. In terms of the "atomicity" that is exactly what I want to solve with this question.

Comment: So, somehow, the EHCCache ensures to only move this to disk when no pending asynchronous computation are ongoing… Then, when following Michael’s approach you only have completed futures in your map at this point of time and should be able to implement a serialization logic for them. It’s just about calling `join` when serializing and `completedFuture` when deserializing.

Comment: I would treat this as an L1/L2 inclusive cache. L1 (heap, future) always loads from L2 (disk) on a cache miss, which computes the value if absent. Then invalidations go L2, L1 for data consistency so that an L1 recompute doesn't cache the stale value on a race.

Comment: @BenManes how would I go about this? Any pointers to relevant code?

Comment: Its like any tiered storage, e.g. cache on top of db. Modify data store, invalidate cache. Here your heap cache loads from disk cache, which loads from db. A write stores in db, invalidates disk cache, then invalidates heap cache. The futures are then async just to hide the latency of the load if your caller can do other useful work instead of blocking. L1=>L2=>...=>Ln on read, Ln=>...=>L2=>L1 on write

Comment: @BenManes There is a nuance in the way I'm thinking about this. The L1 and L2 cache have different elements. L1 has executions represented by completable futures and L2 has the results. The L1 cache should be empty when no executions are taking place, thus taking an element from L2 to L1 when executing a `get` would not make that much sense.

Comment: Yep, and that makes it much harder to coordinate. It's why I started off by saying that "I would treat this as an L1/L2 inclusive cache" as it simplifies the problem significantly. If that does not fit your goals then I think outlining the problem and desired characteristics (vs a solution) would help you judge the pros/cons of different approaches.

Comment: For your `clear()`, one technique that might help you is a generational id. If you support everything else but that method, you can fake it by adding the current version id to the key for all operations. Then when calling `clear()` increment the generation, which forces a cache miss as old entries are no longer visible. You can eagerly clean those out or lazily wait for eviction to handle that. This is a simple trick, but not very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using. I have gone through many revisions but can't find any obvious deadlocks or race conditions. I'm going leave it here just in case it becomes useful for somebody else.

```java
public class AsyncCache {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<Object>> executions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    ReentrantReadWriteLock guard = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    MutableConfiguration<String, Object> configuration = new MutableConfiguration<>();
    Cache<String, Object> results = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager().createCache("results", configuration);

    public CompletableFuture<Object> get(String key, Callable<Object> callable) {

        guard.readLock().lock();
        try {

            // Attempt to get from the cache first. Only pay attention to
            // the cache eviction policies.

            Object result = results.get(key);
            if (result != null) {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
            }

            // Attempt to get from the current executions second. Make sure
            // that the cache and executions is guarded by a read write lock.

            return executions.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {

                CompletableFuture<Object> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        return callable.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new CompletionException(e);
                    }
                }, executor);

                return future.whenComplete((Object r, Throwable t) -> {

                    guard.writeLock().lock();
                    try {
                        if (executions.remove(k) != null) {
                            if (r != null) {
                                results.put(k, r);
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        guard.writeLock().unlock();
                    }

                });

            });

        } finally {
            guard.readLock().unlock();
        }

    }

    public void clear() {

        // Guard the cache and executions with a write lock.

        guard.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            executions.clear();
            results.clear();
        } finally {
            guard.writeLock().unlock();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm still not sure how to check if this is overly restrictive (locking more than needed). For my use case, the callables can take from 100 to 3000 milliseconds, and the clear method can be called every 15 minutes or so.

Perhaps I don't even need the `executions` to be a `ConcurrentHashMap` since the read and writes are protected.